# Constructor not called in Facade

Tags: octobercms

In Laravel I believe the constructor is called when using a Facade class. However with OctoberCMS I have created a Facade, the Class and registered the Class to be injected with the dependency it requires in the Plugin.php file.

ExampleFacade.php

```
class ExampleFacade extends Facade {
    protected static function getAccessor() { return 'example'; }
}
```

Example.php

```
class Example {
    private $dependency;

    __constructor($dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }

    public function doWork()
    {
        $this->dependency->doOtherWork();
    }
}
```

Plugin.php

```
// shortened to save life
public function register()
{
    $this->singleton('example', function($app) {
         return new Example(new Dependency());
    });
}

public function boot()
{
     // registering the facade with the FacadeClass
     \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance()->alias('Example', ExampleFacade::class);
}
```

Calling `Example::doWork();` results in:

```
Cannot call doOtherWork() on NULL
```

Meaning that the dependency was never injected.

Is the constructor just not called in OctoberCMS plugins?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not nearly as complex as I thought.

The Facade pattern allows for constructors - **but**, you need to name them correctly:

Wrong

```
__constructor($dependency)
{
    $this->dependency = $dependency;
}
```

Right

```
__construct($dependency)
{
    $this->dependency = $dependency;
}
```